# Add columns containing the same value in a file with >1M columns

Tags: bash, unix, bioinformatics

I have a very large file with more than a million columns. I need to add a second, third, fourth, fifth and sixth column to the file, with the second column being a copy of the first, and the other columns containing the same value on each row. So for example, I have a file that looks like this:

```
id1 A A C T ..
id2 A G T C ..
id3 G A T C ..
id4 G G T T ..
.   
.
```

And I need to change it to:

```
id1 id1 0 0 -9 -9 A A C T ..
id2 id2 0 0 -9 -9 A G T C ..
id3 id3 0 0 -9 -9 G A T C ..
id4 id4 0 0 -9 -9 G G T T ..
.   
.
```

Any ideas on how to do this efficiently under Unix (since I need to repeat this a lot of times)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sed 's/^\([^ ]*\)/\1 \1 0 0 -9 -9/'
```

If that's not fast enough write a C++ program, it's just a couple of lines.

Comment: I'm guessing you can't make this much faster; it's highly likely that the I/O bottleneck will dominate over the regex overhead.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing we are trying to convert this file into [PLINK ped format](https://www.cog-genomics.org/plink2), if so, then there is no need to add those columns, PLINK can handle [irregular files](https://www.cog-genomics.org/plink2/input) with below flags:

> **Irregularly-formatted PLINK text files**
>
> These allow you to use .fam or .ped files which lack family ID,
>   parental ID, sex, and/or phenotype columns.
>
> ```
> --no-fid
> --no-parents
> --no-sex
> --no-pheno
> ```